# Exit Spring RabbitMQ application on queue declaration error

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I had a task to create a simple Spring RabbitMQ chat application. One of the requirements is that only one user with given nickname can be online at the same time. Users are distinguished by their queue name. Now i have a problem with catching the queue declaration error. In the configuration class I declare a queue bean like so

```
@Bean
public Queue privateQueue(String nickname) {
    String queueName = "prv." + nickname;
    return new Queue(queueName, false, true, true);
}
```

If a queue with `queueName` name already exists, I would like to exit the whole application and print out something like "username taken". What would be the easiest way of doing that? Right now the application retries to create the queue a couple of times and then throws `AmqpIOException` and others due to failed bean creation. Is there a way to catch any of these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

By design, declaring a queue is an idempotent operation. So perhaps, you are not getting an error because the queue already exists.

Anyway, you can check if the queue exists with RabbitMQ HTTP API.

First, add these dependencies in `pom.xml` if they doesn't exist:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>http-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public Queue myQueue(String queueName) {
    Client client = new Client(new ClientParameters()
            .url("http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/").username("guest").password("guest"));

    QueueInfo queue = client.getQueue("/", queueName);

    if (queue == null) { // Does it exist?
        // Write to log, throw exception and etc'
        throw new RuntimeException("Queue " + queueName + " already exists!");
    }

    return new Queue(queueName, true);
}
```